# Backbone bind to "reset" after "fetch" event with Promises

Tags: backbone.js, promise

So I have this pretty simple use-case:

```
init: function() {
    app.products = new app.Collections.Products();
    app.categories = new app.Collections.Categories();

    var collections = [app.products, app.categories];
    var complete = _.invoke(collections, 'fetch');

    $.when(null, complete).then(function(){
       // fetched, but no models
    });
};
```

This works fine from an XHR point of view, but inside the callback, the Models for the respective collections haven't been created yet. Is there a way to also look out for the "reset" event from the "fetch" in this promise-based solution?

Comment: The models should have been created by the time a reset event has been triggered... it doesn't look like you're binding to the reset event here

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I disagree with the duplicate. Some possible overlap, maybe, as your recent edit on your answer demonstrates, but a duplicate is really pushing it.

Comment: @nikoshr his issue is that he does not know how to promisify an API. Even before the recent edit I had a `.onload` case which is _practically the same thing_ - I made the edit "just in case". This question is about turning a callback API (backbone sync events) to a promisified one. These repeat every now and then. There is nothing specific to backbone, or his case here. It is the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own deferred to coordinate your calls. For example, you could add this function on the prototypes of your collections :

```
function promiseSync() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    this.once('sync', function() {
        dfd.resolve();
    });
    return dfd.promise();
}

app.Collections.Products.prototype.promiseSync = promiseSync;
app.Collections.Categories.prototype.promiseSync = promiseSync;
```

And then, exactly as you would do for the requests, combine the deferred:

```
var syncs = _.invoke(collections, 'promiseSync');
$.when.apply(null, syncs).then(function(){
   console.log('syncs');
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/Xb9Mk/

Note the usage of `$.when.apply(null, array)`. `$.when(null, array)` would resolve immediately and that's probably why you don't see your models in your callback.

Answer (score 0):

With this code, you'll have your products and categories collections fetched with their models populated.

The `deferredFetch` function sets up the deferred object and resolves it once the collection is populated. By calling `fetch` with the `{reset: true}` option, Backbone will populate the collection and trigger one `reset` event instead of multiple `add` events.

`init` just fetches both of the collections and `then` executes the commented code block. The `products` and `categories` are passed in because the deferred objects have been resolved with those objects in the `reset` listener.

```
function deferredFetch(collection) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    collection.once('reset', function(collection) {
        deferred.resolve(collection);
    });
    collection.fetch({ reset: true });
    return deferred;
}

init: function() {
    app.products = new app.Collections.Products();
    app.categories = new app.Collections.Categories();

    $.when(deferredFetch(app.products), deferredFetch(app.categories))
     .then(function(products, categories) {
         // do yo thang
    });
}
```